# uwp javascript list files in music library folder

Tags: javascript, uwp

The following lists files in a folder "Assets" in app and functions correctly.

```
// Get the path to the app's Assets folder.
var root = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.current.installedLocation.path;
var path = root + "\\Assets";
//var path = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.musicLibrary; 
var StorageFolder = Windows.Storage.StorageFolder;
var folderPromise = StorageFolder.getFolderFromPathAsync(path);
folderPromise.done(function getFolderSuccess(folder) {
    var filesInFolderPromise = folder.getFilesAsync();
    filesInFolderPromise.done(function getFilesSuccess(filesInFolder) {
        s = "";
        filesInFolder.forEach(function forEachFile(item) {
            s = s + item.name + "<br />";
        });
        document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML = s;
    });
});
```

I want to modify it to list the files in the musicLibrary.  When I change the path name to

```
var path = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.musicLibrary;
```

I get

```
JavaScript runtime error: The parameter is incorrect
```

Please help me with the appropriate syntax.  The musicLibrary capability is set in the manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object is to get the files async from the Music folder.  This is done directly as follows:

```
var f = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.musicLibrary;
f.getFilesAsync().done(function getFilesSuccess(filelist) {
    s = "";
    filelist.forEach(function forEachFile(item) {
        s = s + item.name + "<br />";
    });
    document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML = s;
});
```

Thanks to pnp0a03, and a quick re reading of the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.musicLibrary
```

is not a path string. This is StorageFolder class. Thus the call of getFolderFromPathAsync fails. Please refer the Microsoft docs.

[KnownFolders Class (You can select 'JavaScript' from the language combobox on the right pane)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.KnownFolders#Windows_Storage_KnownFolders_MusicLibrary)

Answer (score 0):

For those struggling with syntax, this answer is equivalent:

```
var f = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.musicLibrary;
f.getFilesAsync().then(success42);
function success42(filelist) {
    s = "";
    filelist.forEach(function forEachFile(item) {
        s = s + item.name + "<br />";
    });
    document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML = s;
}
```